# "Leaking Predicates" error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Wow, I never thought I would cause an error that yields zero hits on Google.

Here's the code that caused it:

```
var otherSessions = 
db.ChildThing.Where(x => x.ID == thingOneID)
  .SelectMany(x => x.ParentThing.ChildThings.SelectMany(x2 => x.GrandchildThings))
  .Where(x=> x.Field1 == null)
  .ToList();
```

And here's the exception:

> System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1004, 0, Leaking predicates.
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Assert(Boolean condition, String message)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinGraph.RebuildNodeTreeForCrossJoins(AugmentedJoinNode joinNode)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinGraph.RebuildNodeTree(AugmentedJoinNode joinNode, Dictionary`2& predicates)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinGraph.RebuildNodeTree(AugmentedNode augmentedNode, Dictionary`2& predicates)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinGraph.RebuildNodeTree(AugmentedJoinNode joinNode, Dictionary`2& predicates)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinGraph.BuildNodeTree()
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinGraph.DoJoinElimination(VarMap& varMap, Dictionary`2& processedNodes)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.ProcessJoinGraph(Node joinNode)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.VisitJoinOp(JoinBaseOp op, Node joinNode)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(InnerJoinOp op, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.InnerJoinOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.VisitDefaultForAllNodes(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.VisitDefault(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.VisitDefaultForAllNodes(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.VisitDefault(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.VisitDefaultForAllNodes(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.VisitDefault(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.JoinElimination.Process()
>      at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
>      at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at MyProject.UIEntities.UserSession.SaveReadingSession(UserSession uiEntity, MyEntities db) in c:\src\MyProject\MyBL\UIEntities\UserSession.cs:line 130

So, any ideas what I broke?

Comment: I rather like the error message 'Leaking Predicates' - well done for finding it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, I discovered the answer while I was posting the question!  The problem is in that lambda `...SelectMany(x2 => x.GrandchildThings)...`

Of course, that should be `x2.GrandchildThings`.  Problem solved.